# What's wrong with my code? My React Native App crashes on calling firestore without any log

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Here's my implementation, I'm storing the baseURL on my firestore database. I used to sign in anonymously in order to get the url. But on calling the firestore, my app crashes without any error, warning, etc.

```
import {create} from 'apisauce';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore, {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const apiClient = create({
  method: 'POST',
});

apiClient.addAsyncRequestTransform(async request => {
  await auth()
    .signInAnonymously()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  const url = await firestore()
    .collection('service_url')
    .doc('service_url')
    .get()
    .then(document => console.log(document.data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  console.log(url);
  request.baseURL = url;
  auth().signOut();
});

export default apiClient;
```

Comment: On doing "adb logcat" I see some log saying something like FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-okhttp-0 java.lang.AssertionError: Method getAlpnSelectedProtocol not supported for object SSL socket over Socket[address=firestore.googleapis.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I faced was the okHTTP. It was not working with Android API 30. So, after  so much workaround, I added the okhttp dependency to my project. That solved my error.